# Deactivate HTML display in incoming emails in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, html

I often get HTML emails, I would like to just display them in plain text. How can I disable any HTML/Script rendering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe you can stop the rendering itself.

The 3 things I know of that you can use are...

1. **View > Message Body As > Plain text**
2. Not use preview (<kbd>f8</kbd> toggles on/off)
3. You can also enable **Tools > Options > Advanced > Privacy > Block loading of remote images** to stop loading remote images (that also kills the ability to execute code from there).

Comment: I have a German 3.1.10 and I cannot find that option.

Comment: In 52.5.2 it's *View* -> *Message Body As* -> *Plain text*.  (...aaand ... it does not work for me.)

Answer (score 0):

View _> Layout _> Message Pane does the same as F8 (#2 above) in Tbird

Comment: is Tbird something other than Thunderbird? I can't find *Layout* in the *View* menu...

Comment: No, Tbird is the shortened name for Thunderbird.  Just like the old cars in the '50s, or '60s?  In version 68.8.0 (64bit for windows), Alt-V does the same as clicking "View" in the menu bar.  If your menu bar is hidden, right-click empty space on the tab bar to toggle display of the menu bar.  "Layout" is the choice between "Toolbars" and "Folders" at the top of the list.  By hovering or clicking Layout, "Message Pane F8" may be checked/unchecked to toggle the message reading pane.